# Dynamically allocate memory for an array of unions inside a struct

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm not sure that I'm approaching this correct, but what I'm trying to do is to dynamically allocate memory for the array of unions inside the struct, I could use

```
Registers regs[20];
```

But I don't want it to be fixed to 20*2 bytes.
Instead I want something like this:

```
typedef union
    uint16_t reg;
    uint8_t low;
    uint8_t high;
}Registers;

typedef struct{
    uint8_t updateIntervall;  
    uint8_t prio;
    Registers *regs;         // <--- Array of unions 
}Config;


uint8_t amount = 4;
Config cfg;
cfg.regs = malloc((amount * 2) * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

And I guess that

```
Config cfg;
```

Already inits the struct, so this should not work.

I'm guessing that I'm doing it completely the wrong way, so if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: You want to allocate `amount` registers. Therefore it should be `malloc((amount * sizeof(Registers))` or better `malloc((amount * sizeof(*cfg.regs))`. The fact that it's inside a struct is irrelevant

Comment: `uint8_t low;
    uint8_t high;`is odd inside an union. I think you meant `union { uint16_t reg; struct { uint8_t low, hight; }}`

Comment: @Jabberwocky why is `malloc((amount * sizeof(*cfg.regs))` better than `malloc((amount * sizeof(Registers))`? Can you please give me a link to where this difference is explained?

Comment: With `x = malloc(amount * sizeof(*x))` we're only talking about `x` and `amount`. With `x = malloc(amount * sizeof(struct somestruct))` you need to be sure that sure `x` is actually a pointer to `struct somestruct`. Nothing prevents you from writing `x = malloc(amount * sizeof(struct someotherstruct))`. The first version is less error prone.

Comment: @Jabberwocky oh, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: We should have some flexible array member canonical dupe, I think. These kind of questions are somewhat common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it another way.  `nregs` is the size of the array

```
typedef struct{
    uint8_t updateIntervall;  
    uint8_t prio;
    Registers regs[];         // <--- Array of unions 
}Config;

Config *cfg=malloc(sizeof(*cfg) + nregs * sizeof(cfg->regs[0]));
```

Comment: I tried this before, but I didnt think I was doing it right, if I check the sizeof(cfg) and increasing the nregs the size does not change.

Comment: @yellowtape it exactly as it should be done. And it works 100% file. You simply do not understand what `sizeof` does.  Sizeof of pointer is not giving the size of the allocated object only size of the pointer itself. In C language there is no way of getting the size of the allocation.

Comment: Okey, that explains a lot. is there a way to see how big cfg actually is ? and a problem now is that I can do cfg.regs[whatever number] more or less, there is no restriction, to get the restriction do I have to specify the size in the struct like Registers regs[MAX_SIZE]  ?

Comment: @yellowtape there is no way in C to see how large the allocated object is. You need to ass additional member to the struct to ster number of regiaters.

Comment: @yellowtape The very definition of this from the C standard goes: "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
have an incomplete array type; this is called a _flexible array member_. In most situations, the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply."